# Beckons (to signal) - Usage

Tags: word-usage

```
Alex beckons me to come nearby.
Alex beckons Sam to come nearby.
Alex beckons Sam to follow him.
```

Does beckons fits well in the above sample sentences or I should better use 'signals' instead as below? I want to mean Alex uses his hands to gesture, so I thought signals doesn't mean the use of hand gestures but beckons does.

```
Alex signals me to come nearby.
Alex signals Sam to come nearby.
Alex signals Sam to follow him.
```

Comment: I use *beckon* exclusively for when you hold your hand out in a loose fist, palm up, and extend your index finger and then bend it inward in a motion that says "come here".  If he *waves* them over or *motions* them over then those are also hand/arm gestures but they aren't *beckoning*.  Others may have a different take on this, though.

Comment: I believe that you can use *beckon* when you move your head in the way that says "come here" too. I think "come here" is the main usage of *beckon*.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting discussion.

The woman in your picture is definitely 'beckoning'. Your usage of the word 'beckon' is correct.

Beckon is a specific gesture. Signal can mean hundreds of gestures. So, beckon is a specific act while signalling can mean anything.

Also, I must remark on the use of the adverb 'nearby', which is incorrect. You must say:

> Alex beckons Sam to come closer.

You mean to say closer than he already is.

Comment: The woman is in *my* answer! ;) where you posting this as a comment to my answer?

Comment: @NeilDSilva Is beckon used only in casual situation? What word would you use when you call someone in a serious situation? The picture in the women seems to be very happy, so I guess this is word won't fit when you call someone when the context is something serious.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO,

For the first two, I'd prefer *beckon* because, it means giving signal with hands or nod

> [beckon (v)](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=beckon) - Signal with the hands or nod

Look at the image, she's beckoning. Here, it seems she's just calling someone nearby and *not asking following*.

[image: Source: depositphoto - only for illustration]

So, when Alex beckons, he asks (whoever) to come nearby.

Now, when you ask someone to follow, I've observed this in movies that the asker either turns a bit to a direction s/he is going and signals or raises eyebrows with a little tilt of face signaling someone to follow them in a particular direction. That way, I think, *signal* fits better than *beckon*.

Also, she *signaled* him to follow is quite common. This is [one of the examples](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/signal_2) on the Oxford.

Note that signal of 'to follow' **may** have an act of beckoning but all in all, it is more than beckoning.

Comment: I think I misunderstood the word. I thought I can use beckon even in the place I gestures my hand by stretching the four fingers straight and folding toward me and repeating this to call someone. So my understanding is wrong? What word I should use in my case?

Comment: @t2e that's okay.